# Reset hover state when leaving current website

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, hover

I have a link (styled as a button):

```
<a href="http://externalsite" class="button" target="_blank">go to external site</a>
```

And I have a hover on this button class, like:

```
.button {
  background-color: green;
}

.button:hover {
  background-color: red;
}
```

So far, no problem. I hover the button, it turns red. I click it and a new page opens in a new tab. When I go back to my website the hover is gone and the button is green again. BUT that only works in some browsers!

In chrome (my version 47.0.2526.80) my button hovers red, I click on the external page and when I go back to my site the button still shows the hovered red color. Only if I move my cursor the hover deactivates. Like somehow the hover is sticky. 
Has anyone experienced this issue? Is this a browser bug? Any ideas for a workaround?

Comment: Could be the :active selector

Comment: does not seem to be the case, if I set :active to green, it still shows red when I reopen the site

Answer (score 0):

Use focus, it did the trick for me :)

Here is a codepen

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/YwEvod

```
.button:focus {
  background-color: green;
}
```

Comment: that works for reappearing the green but now the hover does not work anymore when going back to the site?

Answer (score 0):

```
a:visited, a:focus { 
    color: green;
}
```

try that - if not it may just be chrome

Comment: the color is then the right one, but then the hover does not work anymore (when returning to the page)